# Sort a table using another column in my database table in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I just want to know whether you can sort your database table like this.

```
Id    Priority   Name
1     4          Xyz
2     1          Abc
3     3          Aca
4     6          Anc
5     5          Cbi
```

using the priority column. If so please tell me how to do it in a ruby function.

Comment: But the priority column is not sorted here

Comment: yeah.. my table is like this and i want to write a db command which will get this table sorted

Comment: Did you read the manual? [Active Record Query Interface - Ordering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering)

Comment: give the query you are running to fetch data

Comment: @Stefan thanks man. that was the thing i was searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to sort in accending or descending order

```
Model.order("priority ASC") # to sort it in ascending order
```

or

```
Model.order("priority DESC") # to sort it in descending order
```